# Find the standard matrix of the linear transformation of $T(x,y,3)=(x-y,3-2x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Find the standard matrix of the linear transformation of $T(x,y,3)=(x-y,3-2x)$.

I'm thinking it's
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\3-2x&0\end{bmatrix}$$
but I'm not too sure.

Comment: if $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,\, (x,y)\mapsto (x-y,3-2x)$ then it is not linear, just check that $T(1,0)+T(0,1)\neq T(1,1)$

Comment: I suspect that "3" was supposed to be "z".

Comment: Well, OP is using "3" as a variable. It is not wrong :P (the expression is linear in "3")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that transformation matrices cannot use any of the variables provided to them as input. The 3 is in the input to allow you to put the 3 into $3-2x$ and we are mapping from $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$, so we must have this 2×3 transformation matrix as the answer.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
-2&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$